# Spring OAuth2 - URL Encoded of username within Basic auth header for token endpoint

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

It seems that Basic Auth for token endpoint is not compliant with OAuth2.0 spec, which specifies that the username and password should be URL encoded before being joined with a colon and the base 64 encoded. See [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1)

Creation of the header should be:

```
auth_header = 'Basic' + base64 (urlEncode (client_id) + ':' + urlEncode (client_secret))
```

Hence there needs a URL decode step  after splitting the username from the password.

Spring is just using the BasicAuthenticationFilter to extract the credentials and there doesn't seem a way of extending this to add the URL Decode step.

So, is this an omission from Spring security OAuth2? If so, guess a bug should be raised.
I could replace the BasicAuthenticationFilter, with one that has the URL Decode step, but is there an easier way?

I am currently using Spring Security 5.0.5

Answer (score -1):

Spring security does comply with OAuth 2.0 spec. What you're asking is already covered in `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. Here's an excerpt from the code:

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        boolean debug = this.logger.isDebugEnabled();
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (header != null && header.startsWith("Basic ")) {
            try {
                String[] tokens = this.extractAndDecodeHeader(header, request);

                assert tokens.length == 2;
```

Filter reads the header that has Basic authentication, then it extracts and decode the credentials. 
In the following code, notice that index of colon is used as a String delimiter.

```
private String[] extractAndDecodeHeader(String header, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        byte[] base64Token = header.substring(6).getBytes("UTF-8");

        byte[] decoded;
        try {
            decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Token);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException var7) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Failed to decode basic authentication token");
        }

        String token = new String(decoded, this.getCredentialsCharset(request));
        int delim = token.indexOf(":");
        if (delim == -1) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid basic authentication token");
        } else {
            return new String[]{token.substring(0, delim), token.substring(delim + 1)};
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the decode step above decodes the Base 64 token and then the delimiter splits this into the two parts. index 0: username and index 1: password.
But rfc6749 says that these should url encoded. Hence above needs a further step to URL decode the username and password.
So should be:
return new String[](URLDecoder.decode(token.substring(0, delim)), URLDecoder.decode(token.substring(delim + 1))};

Comment: You're referring to ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded. This indicates that entire form data is sent as a long query string (key value pairs separated by &).  This is not same as URL encoding. Request will be like this: `curl -X POST http://localhost:8443/auth-service/oauth/token -H 'Authorization: Basic UkVXQVJEU19QT1JUQUxfQURNSU4yOnBhc3N3b3Jk' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d grant_type=client_credentials`

Comment: I referring to RFC 6749 (link above), which to my interpretation states that the client id and secret should be url encoded and the encoded values used as the username and password within the basic auth header.